# Binary Search Tree Universe

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

In the world of Binary Search Tree (BST) enthusiasts, where collecting and trading BSTs is a craze, you have a beloved BST with n nodes. In this scenario:

(a) Identifying Swapped Nodes and Common Ancestors (10 points):
Recently, a rival group attempted to steal your prized BST. Although you thwarted their attempt, they still managed to swap two vertices in your BST. You need to develop an algorithm with O(n) complexity to identify the swapped nodes and provide a list of their common ancestors.

(b) Reordering Attack and Counting Nodes (20 points):
In another attack, the rival group rearranged k nodes in your BST, ensuring that none of these k nodes retained their original positions. The values in your BST are bounded by an upper constant G. Your task is to determine the value of k and identify the rearranged nodes. Develop an algorithm with complexity O(min(G + n, n log(n))), considering two cases: when G < n log(n) and when G > n log(n).

```
void inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root, vector<TreeNode*>& nodes) {
    if (root == nullptr)
        return;

    inorderTraversal(root->left, nodes);
    nodes.push_back(root);
    inorderTraversal(root->right, nodes);
}

vector<TreeNode*> findSwappedNodes(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<TreeNode*> nodes;
    inorderTraversal(root, nodes);

    vector<TreeNode*> swappedNodes;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size() - 1; ++i) {
        if (nodes[i]->val > nodes[i + 1]->val) {
            swappedNodes.push_back(nodes[i]);
            swappedNodes.push_back(nodes[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    return swappedNodes;
}

vector<TreeNode*> findCommonAncestors(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* node1, TreeNode* node2) {
    vector<TreeNode*> ancestors;
    TreeNode* current = root;

    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->val > node1->val && current->val > node2->val) {
            ancestors.push_back(current);
            current = current->left;
        } else if (current->val < node1->val && current->val < node2->val) {
            ancestors.push_back(current);
            current = current->right;
        } else {
            break; // Found the lowest common ancestor
        }
    }

    return ancestors;
}
```

This is what I'm thinking for the first part, and for the second part, I am not able to comprehend the conditions.

Comment: Note that on Code Review we only review the code you posted. So we won't say how you should implement (b), that part is better asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or the [Computer Science site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). For the first part, we're missing the definition of `TreeNode`. It would also be nice to see code that can actually be compiled (so add all the `#include`s, `using`s and other things you've used). Also, this looks like questions from some CS exam, and we are usually reluctant to answer those.